# distinct not working on joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the users older than 30 days where is_active = 1 and no records on both table1 and table2

records:

```
tbl_members
---------------------------
id | username | is_active |
 1 |   user1  |     1     |
---------------------------
table1
------------------------------
id | accountid | datecreated |
   |           |             |
------------------------------
table2
------------------------------
id | memberid  | datecreated |
   |           |             |
------------------------------
table3
----------------------------------------
id | memberid  |      datecreated      |
 1 |     1     | 2018-06-21 00:12:51   |
 2 |     1     | 2018-06-22 02:12:51   |
----------------------------------------
```

my query:

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
           a.memberid, 
           c.username,
           d.memberid AS uid,
           d.datecreated 
    FROM   `tbl_members` c 
           LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
                  ON c.`id` = b.`accountid` 
           LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
                  ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
           LEFT JOIN               
           (select distinct memberid, datecreated  from `table3` ) as  d 
                  ON c.`id` = d.`memberid`
    WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
           AND a.memberid IS NULL 
           AND b.accountid IS NULL 
           AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= date(d.datecreated)
    ORDER  BY uid
```

The distinct is not working the results are duplicate instead of only one because the record in table3 is the same user id.

I'm getting the right results but it's duplicated i need to distinct the user in table3

This is my sqlfiddle

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c3f02/1
```

Comment: Because `datecreated` is different

Comment: but i'm accessing it like this d.datecreated, and (select distinct memberid, datecreated  from `table3` ) as  d 
                      ON c.`id` = d.`memberid`

Comment: `distinct ` is applied to whole row in your case combination of `memberid, datecreated` considered as distinct

Comment: try changin  (select distinct memberid, datecreated  from `table3` )
to 
 (select memberid, min(datecreated) as datecreated  from `table3` group by memberid)

Comment: but where's the join on table3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Amila was trying to tell you is you should write something like

```
SELECT b.accountid, 
       a.memberid, 
       c.username,
       d.memberid AS uid,
       d.datecreated 
FROM   `tbl_members` c 
       LEFT JOIN `table1` b 
              ON c.`id` = b.`accountid` 
       LEFT JOIN `table2` a 
              ON b.`accountid` = a.`memberid` 
       LEFT JOIN (select memberid, 
                         MIN(datecreated) datecreated -- or MAX() ...
                  from `table3` group by memberid ) as d
              ON c.`id` = d.`memberid`
WHERE  c.`is_active` = 1 
       AND a.memberid IS NULL 
       AND b.accountid IS NULL 
       AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= date(d.datecreated)
ORDER  BY uid
```

This way table `d` will definitely deliver only one row per `memberid`. And depending on whether you are interested in the first or the last date in table3 use either `MIN()` or `MAX()` on `datecreated`. And as you noticed quite rightly, not `table3` is joined directly to your query but rather the subquery `d`.

Comment: Wow!. works like a charm!. this is what i exactly needed!!